# Sound lagging on HP DV6000 laptop

Tags: laptop, audio, sound-card, lag

I have a HP DV6000 laptop. It's a little over a year old with some wear and tare. The sound is lagging, but I know the cause is not my speakers because the sound lags on my headphones as well.

It will sound ok for a little bit then lag for a little then go back to normal and repeat every few minutes.

This has been happening for a few months, now sometimes if I put my computer on standby and try to listen to music when I log back on there will be no sound and I have to then restart my computer for sound to play.

Answer (score 0):

Check for processes that could be using CPU and impacting the audio. If windows, you can check this in Task Manager.  Simply select the CPU column and watch as you play audio. Be sure to select the Show Processes from All Users button. Also check you have the latest drivers for the audio card.  These will be available at the HP site